# Mock diagnostics?

Tags: ros, simulation, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far I haven't seen any simulated modules that emit `diagnostics` topics. Is there actually one that does so?

Without having a real robot that implements `diagnostics` it's hard to go on making tools that utilize it (eg. [rqt_robot_monitor](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_robot_monitor)). Fixed diagnostic values might be fine as long as there's a variety.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71572/mock-diagnostics?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diagnostics tend to be very specific for a set of drivers, so I don't think you'll find much simulated.

One option might be to use the ArbotiX drivers, as we do have a "sim" mode that simply sort of just echos whatever commands are given to it. You could run the "fake-maxwell.launch" from maxwell_defs found here: https://github.com/mikeferguson/maxwell The robot doesn't publish a ton of diagnostics, but it does publish the state of each controller/joint.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0